# Why is PhantomJS hanging when running Jasmine tests on RequireJS project with Grunt?

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm trying to use the open source [Grunt-Boilerplate](https://github.com/Integralist/Grunt-Boilerplate) project, described in this [blog post](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/grunt-boilerplate/).

I download the [latest.zip](https://github.com/Integralist/Grunt-Boilerplate/archive/master.zip) (commit ref: e7e6b15c2f) and extract the package.

I ran the following to update the dependencies, as listed in the [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/Integralist/Grunt-Boilerplate/blob/master/Gruntfile.js):

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-requirejs --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-htmlmin --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-connect --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-jasmine --save-dev
npm install grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs --save-dev
npm install grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul --save-dev
npm install load-grunt-tasks --save-dev
npm install time-grunt --save-dev
```

Once completed, when I run `grunt jasmine` PhantomJS seems to hang forever at this stage:

```
tom ~/_tmp/Grunt-Boilerplate-master ϟ grunt jasmine
>> Local Npm module "grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs" not found. Is it installed?    

Running "jasmine:run" (jasmine) task
Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS
```

**What is the problem here? And how can I resolve the issue so that I can run Jasmine with grunt?**

---

**Context**

Updated `package.json` (following `npm install ... --save-dev`)

```
{
  "name": "Integralist",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "This is a project set-up using Grunt to take case of some standard tasks such as: compiling AMD based modules using RequireJS, watching/compiling Sass into CSS, watching/linting JS code and some other things such as running unit tests",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.7.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.8.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.6.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:Integralist/Grunt-Boilerplate.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Grunt",
    "JavaScript"
  ],
  "author": "Mark McDonnell",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

PhantomJS version:

```
tom ~/_tmp/Grunt-Boilerplate-master ϟ phantomjs -v
1.9.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for the [Grunt-Boilerplate](https://github.com/Integralist/Grunt-Boilerplate) project you need to run the task `grunt test` task instead of `grunt jasmine`, in order to ensure that the Connect server is running before the jasmine tests.

Ref: https://github.com/Integralist/Grunt-Boilerplate/issues/5#issuecomment-50967508